# Show only the real matches in clock table - without their parent headlines

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-tags

The clock table of org mode has so many great features but I couldn't find this:
I'd like to have only the headlines with a specific tag *without* their parents.

Example

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope file  :match "thisTag" :tags t
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2020-04-28 Tue 14:04]
| Tags    | Headline           | Time   |      |
|---------+--------------------+--------+------|
|         | *Total time*       | *0:05* |      |
|---------+--------------------+--------+------|
|         | parent headline    | 0:05   |      |
| thisTag | \_  child headline |        | 0:05 |
#+END:



* parent headline
** child headline  :thisTag:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2020-04-28 Tue 12:00]--[2020-04-28 Tue 12:05] =>  0:05
:END:
```

Only the 'child' has the tag 'thisTag' but the table mentions also the parent. This could be helpful but I'd like to keep the table small: to show only the headlines with the tag 'thisTag', so without 'parent headline' -- something like this:

```
| Tags    | Headline           | Time   |
|---------+--------------------+--------|
|         | *Total time*       | *0:05* |
|---------+--------------------+--------|
| thisTag | child headline     | 0:05   |
```

How to get it?